# Oracle: dynamic SQL statement based on a mapping table

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

Take the following statements in order to create the context in this [page](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    CREATE TABLE TABLEA (COLUMN_A VARCHAR2(30));
    CREATE TABLE TABLEB (COLUMN_B VARCHAR2(30));
    CREATE TABLE MAPPING_TABLE (TABLEA_COL VARCHAR2(30), TABLEB_COL VARCHAR2(30));
    INSERT INTO MAPPING_TABLE (TABLEA_COL, TABLEB_COL) VALUES ('COLUMN_A', 'COLUMN_B');
COMMIT;
```

I want to make a select from `TABLEB` using the mapping value setted in the `MAPPING_TABLE`.

In other words, knowing the name of the column of the `TABLEA` (for example 'COLUMN_A'), I want to make a `SELECT` directly in the `TABLEB`.

Something like:

```
SELECT /*a statement to recover the COLUMN_B based on the 'COLUMN_A' value*/ 
FROM TABLEB
```

It is possible to do in SQL statement, or I'm forced to use PL/SQL context (with procedures, etc...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare
  v_col varchar(30);
  v_val varchar(30);
  sql_stmt varchar(255);
begin
  select tableb_col into v_col
  from mapping_table 
  where tablea_col = 'COLUMN_A';

  sql_stmt := 'select '||v_col||' from tableb';

  dbms_output.put_line ( sql_stmt ) ;

  execute immediate sql_stmt into l_val;

  dbms_output.put_line ( v_val) ;
end;
```